# Determine the constant for a and b so that the function h(x) is continuous everywhere.

Tags: calculus, continuity

I was trying to find one similar to mine but couldn't find one that had 2 values for x and only 1 equation with an x.

$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
2, & x\le -1 \\
ax+b, & -1\lt x \lt 3 \\
-2, & x \ge 3 \\
\end{cases}
$

I got a total of 4 equations when x is -1 and x is 3 for $a$ and $b$ respectively.

$b = 2 + a$ and $b = -2 - 3a$

$a = -2 + b$ and $a = \frac{-2-b}{3}$

Do I just set them equal to each other? Editted: I got $a = -1$ and $b = 1$ After setting the $b$ equations equal to each other and solving for a, and then setting the $a$ equations equal to each other and solving for b. Graphed it and it's correct.

Edit: Noticed that I had an equation wrong. Sign should be a plus not a negative to $b = 2 + a$.

Edit: Just graphed it to make sure it was correct; it is.

Comment: Your equation $b=2-a$ seems to have a sign wrong (it should be $b=2+a$) but your other equations are correct. It's worth noting there are only two distinct equations, and if you solve them you should get $(a, b) = (-1,1).

Comment: How do yo get 4 equations? I just got two. At x = -1, ax + b = 2 and at x = 3, ax + b = -2.
And your 2nd and 4th equations are same.

Comment: Thanks! I was wondering how it as 2 because I graphed it and it didn't make sense... I noticed that the graph is true when a is -1 so I realized there must be something wrong until you told me. Thanks!

Comment: I got 4 equations because you solve for a and b when x is -1. And you solve for a and b when x is 3. So you get 2 a = and 2 b= equations.

Comment: What you are saying as $4$ equations, that is actually $2$ equations. Last $2$ equations are the same.

Comment: haha you're right. All I had to do once I got "a" was plug in and solve for "b".

Comment: Also, it is not clear to me at least what do you want to find. Also you can not comment anything about $f(-1^+)$ and $f(3^-)$ unless it is mentioned that the function is continuous.

Comment: You have to find the values of "a" and "b" so that the line is continuous, as it is not currently. If you graph it, you will see what I mean. There are 2 discontinuities at x = -1 and x = 3 for the function "ax+b". Basically, what does "a" and "b" have to be in order to connect the 3 functions together? At "a = -1" and "b = 1".